# Convert set or array of points to polygon in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, geometry, postgis

I have a function that performs a transform on points.

I've figured out how to convert a polygon into a set of points and transform each point with a custom function I wrote. But I can't figure out how to now convert the points back into a polygon.

Here's my code that returns an array of transformed points. How do I get a polygon from this?

```
SELECT  array_agg(point_geotransform(point((dp).geom))) As p
FROM    (SELECT ST_DumpPoints(polygon(circle('((0,0),10)'))::geometry) AS dp
        ) t;
```

Ps. If there is a more efficient way of extracting the points, I'd love to know.

Answer (score 0):

This works (excluded the transform so others can see it works):

```
SELECT  polygon(circle('((0,0),10)')) p
UNION ALL
SELECT  ST_MakePolygon(ST_MakeLine((point((dp).geom))::geometry))::polygon p
FROM    (SELECT ST_DumpPoints(polygon(circle('((0,0),10)'))::geometry) AS dp
    ) t;
```

Geometry must be converted to geometry and polygon to polygon, so to speak.